# how to hide the progress bar in android while using asynctask

Tags: android-intent, android-asynctask

How can I hide the **`progressbar`** in a normal program. I used the code:

```
registerAsyncTask = new RegisteAsyncTask(infogateway,getApplicationContext());
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
registerAsyncTask.execute(phone, name, null,gender,password, email, null,null,null,role,null,null);
```

Where do I have to make the progressbar invisible?

Comment: Maybe you can use AsyncTask. I normally dont get any progressbar with that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Official Guide [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

```
protected void onPreExecute()
  { 
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Pre-Execute");
 super.onPreExecute(); 
 pb.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE); 
  } 


    private class doSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                //Inflate you view or do anything here before loading stuff
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
                //loading stuff
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                //change your UI - like a progressbar
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
                //Hide the progressbar
            }
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting visible in `onPreExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and set invisible when you finish your task in `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
}
```